# Android Traceview - It holds the Answers to my Unresponsive App... I think

Tags: android, methods, webkit, cpu, bitmapfactory

Yesterday, I spent 12 hours becoming a student of Traceview. I didn't even know it existed (hangs head in shame) previous to this.

Now that I've overcome the absolute shock of the data it produces, I find Traceview can be boiled down into a couple simple concepts:

1. Sort by "EXCL CPU TIME" to determine exactly how much usage each individual method is using in isolation.
2. Look at the frequency of calls and the cpu time/real time per call. Obviously higher calls should be looked into. In most of my experience, if you sort by #1 above, methods which are called too much and take too much time will also be at the top of the list (makes sense as they are also using the most CPU).

Anyway, doing these two steps above I find 3-4 methods which are always using 90% of my CPU and taking up most of the real time delays in my app. The only problem is, none of these methods are methods I wrote, they are system methods such as:

1. BitmapFactory methods
2. WebKit methods
3. And other system methods

This being said, is it a correct to assume that if the top resource hogs are system methods, then it must have something to do with my design of my layouts? I am at a loss as to how BitmapFactory could be so high, my layouts aren't extremely complicated, though in one Activity BitmapFactory is taking 95% of resources itself.

**TL;DR - If I run a Traceview, and if I find the top hogs of resources are all system methods, does this mean it's a layout issue? Or, how else can I tell why the system method is so high as it doesn't relate directly to my custom methods.**

Thank you very much,
Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the problem and it's bitter sweet. It's sweet because it wasn't my code nor layout causing the problem, it was the admob AdView using the loadAdOnCreate="true" to create ads. It's bitter, because I now may have to switch sources of revenue if I can't remove the loading delay created by the AdView! That was a tough one to find, I should have anticipated this though!

Answer (score 3):

> I find Traceview can be boiled down into a couple simple concepts:

Those concepts are not the best, IMHO.

> Sort by "EXCL CPU TIME" to determine exactly how much usage each individual method is using in isolation

In particular, this concept is fairly lousy IMHO. Yes, this is useful data. However, you then need to work *back up the call stack* to try to figure out what is triggering this. Sometimes, it will directly be your code. Sometimes, it will be something else that you recognize that is part of the framework (e.g., `onDraw()` of a `View`). Just knowing that some random method is taking up a bunch of time does you no good until you identify *what* is triggering that method to be invoked in the first place.

> If I run a Traceview, and if I find the top hogs of resources are all system methods, does this mean it's a layout issue?

No.

> Or, how else can I tell why the system method is so high as it doesn't relate directly to my custom methods.

Work your way up the call stack to figure out who is calling these methods so frequently, or at inopportune times.

For example, in the `BitmapFactory` example, you will probably find that you (or a library that you are using) is calling `BitmapFactory`, and perhaps is doing so on the main application thread.

To work your way up the call stack, click the triangle on the left edge of the row representing some method of interest. You will then see two branches beneath that: "Parents" and "Children". The "Parents" represent the next level up the call stack from the method, and you can continue working your way up the chain of parents until you find something that you recognize.

That's why, IMHO, you are better served sorting by *inclusive* time, as your code (where it directly is the culprit) will tend to bubble towards the top.

Comment: Thank you, this is the best explanation for Traceview debugging I've seen on the Internet yet. Most tutorials stop at explaining how to track down your issue. Thank you so much for your help, I've been traversing the stack, though, mostly drilling down the stack. I see your point about drilling up the stack to see what is actually firing the method that's a hog... So far, I don't recognize anything, but, I believe I'm better suited now! Thank you, this is why I buy your books.

Comment: @AutoM8R: Thanks for the kind words! FWIW, I've had a chapter on Traceview in [*The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development*](http://commonsware.com/Android) for at least a year.

Comment: I was afraid you'd say that. I bought that very book. I'll admit though, I have difficulties focusing and I read sections that interest me one at a time. I guess I never even knew what Traceview was, so I was oblivious to it. I will obviously read this now, perfect realization.

Comment: Well, I found the problem and it's bitter sweet. It's sweet because it wasn't my code nor layout causing the problem, it was the admob AdView using the loadAdOnCreate="true" to create ads. It's bitter, because I now may have to switch sources of revenue if I can't remove the loading delay created by the AdView! That was a tough one to find, I should have anticipated this though!